# PHP eval():: Use of undefined constant not_a_constant- assumed 'not_a_constant' php 7.2

Tags: php, undefined, eval, php-7.2

This code gives the warning of the title.
Simplest solution would be to add the single quotes to "not_a_constant".
This however break the "eval"
I have tried concatenation of strings, etc.

The eval SHOULD NOT BE removed.
No auxiliary variables should be used.

```
eval('$some_defined_var[not_a_constant] .= "' . some_function('some_string') . '";')
```

Please try this code defining some dumb vars and functions with php 7.2 to check the warning and possible solutions.

**Edit**
1)Code standards forbids to use doble quotes for string.s
2)We are trying to avoid scaping the single quotes inside the indexing in the "not_a_constant".
This means, what I'm trying to achieve is this:

> $some_defined_var['not_a_constant']

Comment: Try adding double-quotes around the array key: `$some_defined_var["not_a_constant"]`

Comment: Sorry, im adding some edits. code standards forbids:
1)Doble quotes for strings.
2)In this case  try not to use \' (scapping single quotes).
This means, I need to achieve this: some_defined_var['not_a_constant'] (single quotes) :-)

Comment: I knows it sucks, just rules hahah, it is a nice exercise anyway

Comment: You want to add single quotes within a string, but you aren't allowed to use double quotes or escape single quotes? You're boxing yourself into a corner a bit, here.

Comment: Inside the indexing, yes, trying to avoid escaping.
Outside, in the concatenation, I may use double quotes, escaping, just not inside the indexing.
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you can't escape single quotes?  The error you are getting is because you aren't telling php you are using a string. When it finds no constant with that name it falls back to using it as a string.

Comment: Any coding standard that "forbids" something, even at the expense of making code less readable, is a Bad Coding Standard. I'd also argue that applying your coding standards to code *that your code is generating* is a massive waste of everyone's time. Use double quotes around it.

Comment: Just in case "eval fine, double-quoted strings banned" isn't already an obviously ridiculous rule, you're seeing this message for the first time in PHP 7.2 because [it was changed from a "notice" to a "warning"](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate-bareword-strings). Presumably, your coding standard only cares about warnings, but **this code was always wrong**, and would break horribly if anyone wrote `define('not_a_constant', 'something_completely_different')`. This code is so many degrees of broken it's kind of hilarious.

Comment: You have code standards that disallow double quotes, but use `eval`? Sounds like a really laughable standard.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't escape single quotes and are forbidden to use double quotes, you are left with heredoc and nowdoc. The [manual](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php) shows you how to use them. For your code you could go with:

```
<?php
$some_defined_var['not_a_constant'] = 'old ';

function some_function($a) { return 'New '.$a;}

eval( <<<'EOE'
$some_defined_var['not_a_constant'] .= "
EOE
. some_function('some_string') . '";'
);

var_dump($some_defined_var);
```

Please note that I normally would not suggest to code anything like this. I'm just applying your restriction. And I fully agree with all the commentators who don't like your coding standard.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment:

> Inside the indexing, yes, trying to avoid escaping. Outside, in the concatenation, I may use double quotes, escaping, just not inside the indexing.

I think one of these might meet your rather arcane rules:

```
eval('$some_defined_var[' . "'not_a_constant'" . '] .= "' . some_function('some_string') . '";')

eval("\$some_defined_var['not_a_constant'] .= \"" . some_function('some_string') . '";')
```

It feels like there's some missing context here as to why you're actually using `eval`, since the example you give could just be rewritten as:

```
$some_defined_var['not_a_constant'] = (string)some_function('some_string');
```

Or possibly as:

```
$some_defined_var['not_a_constant'] = eval('"'. some_function('some_string') . '"');
```

Since `some_function` could return code that did whatever it wanted when `eval`'d, e.g.

```
function some_function($who_cares) {
    return '"; var_dump($config["database_password"]); "';
}
```

The rules about double-quotes etc might make sense if we knew which parts were dynamic, because it might be an attempt at securing the `eval`; but frankly, the only way to secure `eval` is not to use it.